# Arrays implementation in erlang

Tags: memory, erlang, immutability

My question is, how are arrays implemented in Erlang, as opposed to lists.

With immutable types doing things like,

```
move ([X | Xs], Ys) ->
    [X | Ys].

Ls = move([1,2,3], [2,3,4])
```

would take up constant mem in the heap, since this is all reference work.

But for the same stuff in arrays

```
move (A1, A2) ->
    array:set(0, array:get(0,A1),A2).

A1 = array:from_list([1,2,3]).
A2 = array:from_list([0,2,3,4]).
A3 = move(A1,A2).
```

Will `move` here use size proportional to A2 or will it be able to do this in constant space like with the arrays?

Comment: The `array` module builds a nested tuple structure. It is both size and speed efficient.

Comment: @rvirding, what do you mean by a nested tuple structure? are you telling me that lookups are not O(1)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To (hopefully) clear things up a little. Remember that in Erlang **ALL** data is immutable! This profoundly affects how you manipulate data.

The `array` module builds a structure of nested tuples where all the array slots containing data are at the same level. The size of each tuple is 10 so for array access we have O(lg10(N)). Using  nested structure like this is common in languages with immutable data. You *could* keep an array in a flat tuple which would give you fast reads, but writes would become slow and memory hogging for large arrays/tuples as every write would entail creating a new tuple. Using a tree structure means that much less data is created in a write.

How your `move/2` function affects memory usage depends a little on whether you are writing to a used or unused slot in the array. If the slot is already in use then the resultant memory usage will be the same. If you are writing to a previously unused slot then you may need to grow the array which mean that more memory will be used.

This is exactly the same as for your list case.

It also depends on whether there are any remaining references to the old data structure.

Comment: I see what your saying, and I do agree that arrays are incompatible with pure functional programming, and immutable datatypes -- however erlang is a strange bag of bees, and stuff like ets, digraph and other tricks could mean that it was posible to do arrays in a hack like way. An array could be implemented so that get and set, just mutated a c nif or something else wierd.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen you *could* use NIFs but if you write into erlang process heaps then you should definitely avoid mutating data, the gc is not expecting it and you will get strange behaviour. ETS is actually quite close to a process if you think about it, for example it is linked to processes and goes away if they die. So it is not as bad as it first seems.

Comment: @rvinding, I bet I could destroy Erlang, and implement an array that had its data in the system heap, and setup a monitor that cleaned it up in case the owner died. But yes if it is allocated on the process-heap, everything sorta breaks.My conclussion is that the naming is sorta ... misleading, since it indicates O(1) updated to the structure, and that is not the case.

Comment: @MartinKristiansen, probably. The name isn't too bad, it is at least something indexed like "normal" arrays. And I don't think it claims to be O(1). :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/array.erl). It looks like, as @rvirding mentioned, that an array is a functional tree. I haven't studied the implementation deeply--and there's no reference in the source to the data-structure's origin--but a quick skim suggests a lookup worst-case is some logarithmic factor of N.

I'd love a correction if someone else is more familiar with this source / has a moment to study it.

Comment: I looked at the output of array:from_list(lists:duplicate(N, )1), and it looks like tomething with out constant lookup and update -- basically its some sort of tree.