# Erlang array vs list

Tags: arrays, performance, list, erlang, comparison

I'm new to Erlang so I am working on an example program and struggling to decide whether I should use an array or a list. Both are easy to create and handle but I didn't get:

- How you append an item to an array without knowing an index of where it should be appended. Is `array:set(array:size(A),"a",A)` the way to go?
- How to find out if a certain element is a member of the array, just as the `lists:member()` function does. Do I have to iterate through the entire array and check each element for this?

And last, which one is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Rule of thumb: Use lists unless it is obvious you shouldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Lists are a data type that is native to the Erlang VM. Arrays are implemented as a structure of nested tuples.**

Lists can be used in pattern matching. Arrays shouldn't be.

As @zxq9 mentioned, lists should be used unless it's obvious that you shouldn't. The only time I think you should use an array is when a lot of random updates are performed on the collection. Otherwise just use a list.

- As you mentioned, appending to an array can be done with `array:set(array:size(A),"a",A)`. Prepending to a list can be done with `["a"|A]`. Of course if you wanted to append to the list you could run `lists:reverse` followed by `["a"|A]` followed by another call to `lists:reverse`.
- To check if an item exists in an array, you could convert the array to a list (`array:sparse_to_list(A)`). Then call `lists:member/2` on the resulting list.

More information on the array implementation available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16464349/1245380

Answer (score 4):

If you think that you may need a function like lists:member/2, use a list :o)

Array brings value when it makes sense to access any element by its index, avoiding list exploration or boring tuple matches like `{_,_,_,_,_,_,N,_,_,_,_} = Tuple,` which is nicely replaced by `N = array:get(6,Array)`. (or `element(7,Tuple)`, but with tuples you don't have map, sparse_pap, foldl ...).